# How to move up solution files in directory hierarchy correctly?

Tags: c#, asp.net, projects-and-solutions

For some reason I have a solution with a single project and the solution files are in the same directory as the project is. I consider this ugly and want to change it by moving the solution files in a superordinate directory.

For now I have edited a single line in the .sln file:

```
Project("{FAE04EC0-AAAA-AAAA-AAAA-00C04F79EFBC}") = "projectname", "projectname.csproj", "{5D5A753D-AAAA-AAAA-AAAA-C535851E8DC8}"
```

changed to

```
Project("{FAE04EC0-AAAA-AAAA-AAAA-00C04F79EFBC}") = "projectname", "directoryname/projectname.csproj", "{5D5A753D-AAAA-AAAA-AAAA-C535851E8DC8}"
```

It seems to work.

Could this have been all I needed to change? I have the feeling that I missed something. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's all I do when I move slns.  It's never failed me.

Answer (score 3):

Projects are independents from solution.

So you are not missing something. Solutions are just a nice way to easily link projects together.